# Dash Page not opening up

Tags: python, python-3.x, dashboard, web-frameworks, plotly-dash

I have a small piece of code here below. The issue here is the Dash Page does not start up. It pops a small icon naming "Loading...." , and the Page doesnt show up. I have tried couple of things but nothing works.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div('Dash Tutorials')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The main problem is server does starts and No error is shown. Would be a great help if someone could sort the reasons for this. Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Nisarg

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a frontend/javascript code issue. Please check what's going on in the the browser via js console.

Answer (score 0):

start the server from the project folder, not through the programming environment

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Just make sure that if you are running it from a virtual machine (or any machine outside of localhost) that you listen to the right IP.
So you can change it like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port='8050')
```

Setting my `host=0.0.0.0`  allows my server to listen to any IP, and you will use this URL:

```
http://<YourIp>:8050
```

You can check your IP via these commands:

```
$: ip addr / ifconfig

>: ipconfig
```

Comment: I missed your layout:      dashboard.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children='Hello World')
    ])